# How to sort rows and columns in one list jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

Do You know how can i make sorting in jquery in 2 axis? I have rows and columns in list like on this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ahta.jpg).
and i must change seats columns and rows. I tried to use sortable from jQuery but its working only in one axis.

I tried to do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/edw6eqw2/1/

```
 <ul id="sortable">
  <li>
    <div class="title">KOLUMN A</div>
    <div class="second-col">KOLUMB B</div>
    <div class="main-payment">KOLUMN C</div>
    <div class="interest">KOLUMN D</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">KOLUMN A, ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="second-col">KOLUMN B, ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="main-payment">KOLUMN C, ITEM 1</div>
    <div class="ddd interest">KOLUMN D, ITEM 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">KOLUMN A, ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="second-col">KOLUMN B, ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="main-payment">KOLUMN C, ITEM 2</div>
    <div class="ddd interest">KOLUMN D, ITEM 2</div>
  </li>
       <li>
    <div class="title">KOLUMN A, ITEM 3</div>
    <div class="second-col">KOLUMN B, ITEM 3</div>
    <div class="main-payment">KOLUMN C, ITEM 3</div>
    <div class="ddd interest">KOLUMN D, ITEM 3</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>  
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      axis: 'y'
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

but i can sorting only rows. I need also replace whole column C with column D.

Thanks for Your help.